# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /srv/disk3/1627618/www/*********/includes/classes/class.register.php on line 25

Tags: php

I'm currently coding something (otherwise I wouldn't be here...) and I'm running in to an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /srv/disk3/1627618/www/*********/includes/classes/class.register.php on line 25
```

I've read alot of topics on the same subject, most of them were like forgotten comma's and stuff. I read my code many times but I don't see it. This is it:

```
 $this->db_connection = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DATA);
        if (!$this->db_connection->set_chatset("utf8")) {
            $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
        }
        if ($this->db_connection->connect_errno) {
            $user_name = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
            $login = "SELECT user_name, user_password_hash FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name"';";
            $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($login);
            if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {
                $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();
```

Does someone see the mistake I made?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You missed a `.` in this line: `$login = "SELECT user_name, user_password_hash FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name"';";`.

Answer (score 0):

You need another `.` on this line:

```
$login = "SELECT user_name, user_password_hash FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "';";
```